# Can the Coerce action be used on a PC?

Tags: skills, racial-traits, pathfinder-2e, intimidation

While this is a way to take away player agency, the second part of the [Haughty Obstinacy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=69) feat says: "*If a creature rolls a failure on a check to Coerce you using Intimidation, it gets a critical failure instead (so it can’t try to Coerce you again for 1 week)*"

Such feat is not rare or available to NPC's only, and it wasn't addressed in the errata. Does this technically mean that a PC can be coerced? I do not intend on using the Coerce action as GM on any player, but I'm curious to know if that would technically be a house-rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes ...

The description of the Coerce activity says that you can target any creature:

> With threats either veiled or overt, you attempt to bully **a creature** into doing what you want. You must spend at least 1 minute of conversation with **a creature** you can see and that can either see or sense you ... (CRB, pg. 247)

Player characters are creatures, so it definitely seems that a PC can be targeted by Coerce.

### ... but not really

The Coerce rules also reference the "Changing Attitudes" sidebar on page 246-247. This sidebar makes it clear that while players may use social skill checks to measure how influential their character is, ultimately a PC is governed by their player's choice - not the die roll.

> ... You can roleplay interactions with player characters, and even use Diplomacy results if the player wants a mechanical sense of how convincing or charming a character is, but players make the ultimate decisions about how their characters respond. (CRB, pg. 247)

So why have Haughty?  First, NPCs with this feat limit how often a PC can attempt to Coerce them. There isn't any apparent mechanical benefit to a PC from this clause, because the player is responsible for determining their response anyway.

Nonetheless, there could be some benefits in skill challenges where a Coerce action is used in a non-traditional way. Published Paizo adventures often contain mini-games where skills and activities are used in non-traditional ways. For example, in *The Flooded King's Court* PCs can attempt Perform actions to convince a nobleman to allow them access to a dungeon. They are performing (so the Perform activity is narrative relevant), but the results are different than the Perform action's ordinary results. Although I don't know of any examples using Coerce, there is at least precedent for these kinds of uses.

Comment: Then how could you - or anyone for that matter - use the second part of the feat? Would it just be ignored for PCs? Would you use the Coerce action similarly to the Demoralize action? I'm curious.

Comment: @Elmoserpe I suspect it would be beneficial to NPCs to have that feat, to limit the result of a PCs attempt to Coerce them. I'll edit this in.